# Change default option in Search and Select Prompt in Cognos Analytics

Tags: javascript, analytics, cognos

I am trying to configure the Search And Select Prompt in Cognos Analytics (Release 6 and above) to change the default option from "Starts with any of these keywords" to "Contains any of these keywords" --> 3rd option.

All the documentation and information available over the internet uses a JavaScript code that works fine until Full Interactivity is enabled!

I know that I need to move the code a separate JS file and call it through a Custom Control of Page Module. I tried both and looks like that the same JavaScript code won't work.

On the other hand, I've went in depth through the official documentation of "Scriptable Reports" from IBM which describes all technical details regarding the new Prompt API, but without any luck to understand how to simply change that option (I don't want to getValues, or clearValues, or setValues!. I simply want to change the default option)

Any help would be highly appreciated!

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You will have to go outside of the Cognos Prompt API to manipulate the default Search & Select option. My instructions below apply to 10.2, the only system I currently have access to. Some of the steps may have changed for Cognos 11, but the concept is the same.

The first thing to do is to put an HTML object right before your Search & Select with the following code:

```
<span id="test">
```

Next, put another HTML object right after the Search & Select with the following code:

```
</span>
<script>
document.getElementById('test').getElementsByTagName('input')[2].setAttribute('checked','');
</script>
```

This will select the 3rd option (index 2) in the Search & Select.

Finally, if you want the default to only be set on initial rendering and preserve any choice the user has made on rerprompt, you can modify the code as follows:

```
...
<script>
if (typeof initialized == 'undefined') {
    document.getElementById('test').getElementsByTagName('input')[2].setAttribute('checked','');
    initialized = true;
}
</script>
```

For more information on this technique, you can see my blog post here:

[Javascript: Running Code Only Once](http://cogblogger.com/2014/10/javascript-running-code-only-once/)